# Play DRM content in React Native

Tags: javascript, react-native, react-native-video

How do I play DRM content in React Native without using any native modules? It is a pure JS app. I have tried using the React Native Video library but they don't support DRM as yet.

Comment: Use [`react-native-video`](https://github.com/yaraht17/react-native-video). They say that support drm [more info](https://github.com/react-native-community/react-native-video/pull/789)

Comment: @MohsenMd That build has not yet been merged into the main project.